# Git adds second file to old repository and not to new repository

Tags: git, repository, commit

I have two folders and .git (after git init) and I want to create 2 repositories:

1. C
2. CPP

I created C repository with:

```
git init
git add C
git commit -m "."
git remote add origin https://github.com/tomerbarak11/C.git
git push -u origin master
```

Then I created the second repository CPP like this:

```
git init
git add CPP
git commit -m "."
git remote add origin https://github.com/tomerbarak11/CPP.git
git push -u origin master
```

First, when I executed the second commit for some reason it started to reupload the files(it added them in add already)
and when I wrote commit it said `fatal: remote origin already exists.`
I tried to push it anyway and it added all files to the C repository and CPP repository is empty.

How to solve?

Comment: It sounds like you ran `git init` in the same directory each time. Once Git has created a repository, a *second* `git init` is largely a do-nothing-at-all operation. (The later `git init` has a side effect with hooks and hook templates, but this is an advanced feature that you are not using.)

Answer (score 0):

`git init` creates a git repository in the current directory according to it's manual (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init). This means when you run `git init; git add C`, it will create a repository in your current directory.

What you probably intent is creating a new repository called C and one called CPP as follows:

1. Assuming you are currently in a directory called `~/src`: `git init C`;

   1. this creates a new directory C with a folder `C/.git` which is the root of the repository.
   2. `cd C; git remote add origin https://github.com/tomerbarak11/C.git`, will correctly setup the origin
2. Back to `~/src`, repeat: `git init CPP`

   1. this creates a new directory C with a folder `C/.git` which is the root of the repository.
   2. `cd C; git remote add origin https://github.com/tomerbarak11/CPP.git`, will correctly setup the origin

If you run `git init` without a directory name it will create a local .git repository and you will accidentally operate within that at all times.